# Queuing requests when network connection is slow or fails

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have an AngularJS/Cordova application for iOS which makes calls to a remote API.

Sometimes, our users have slow or low-quality connection on their mobile phones, and therefore cannot perform a certain action on the phone.

During this time, the user can tap on other buttons which fires off more network requests, and they become queued up and causes the application to hang.

What would be the best way to help remedy this situation? I was thinking of the following options:

1. Requests that time out after a certain n seconds will simply be aborted.
2. Use debounce to wait n msecs before firing off a request, and cancel the timer if the user does something else (this still wouldn't account for failed requests that are made on the slow network).
3. Add failed/timed out requests to a queue, and send them later when there is a more reliable connection (not sure how to accomplish this).

Does anyone know of any other solutions -- and any ideas on implementation?

Any advice highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple safest way to prevent to user to invoke additional request - to use loader that blocks page till get any response/error. Its not demands complicated logic and therefore maintenance.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes in the field, the loader just spins indefinitely even though I have error callbacks set to remove the loader. It seems as though the connection is just really slow an an error is never returned.

Comment: You can create timer and implement timeout, or add timeout to connection

Comment: The issue is that I'm looking to provide a better experience for the user -- anything that can make it "feel" smoother, e.g. queuing up the requests and sending them later, would be preferred over a 10-second loading spinner and then an error message. Sorry if I sound like I'm being difficult but it's just the requirements of the project.

Comment: Why not, its cellular, sometimes you try to login to Skype and get error after 20 sec, its user problem of low network throughput

Comment: It's just simply part of the requirements. It needs to perform well in the field.